# Lock/unlock form with toggle

Tags: forms

I'm looking for a way to have a button toggeling the field of my form. When "locking" the form with the toggle button no data can be typed. When "unlocking" data should be allowed to be typed. What I want to achieve with this is simple avoiding users to accidentally type.

I found the code below and it works. Only problem is that it only applies to one input field. I want it to work on more that one.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox">
<input type="text" id="yourText">
<script>
document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = this.checked;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the fields you want to disable with a CSS class, and then use jQuery to disable them.

[jQuery - Disable Form Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387341/jquery-disable-form-fields)

If you want a pure Javascript solution, just repeat this line

```
document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = this.checked;
```

for each field.

Or, you can do something like this this: [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808808/102937).  Note that you can assign multiple CSS classes to the same field, so assign another class to identify those fields that need to be disabled.

Comment: If the code provided uses plain old JS, better to provide a plain old JS solution?

Comment: Is there another way? I already use the class for css style :/

Comment: @user2662616 Your elements have IDs, but not classes

Comment: Well the class I use for css style is just not in the example in the post.

Comment: <input class="thestyle" class="lockfunction"></input> like that?